# Shutting down ForkJoinPool causes program to print exception and hang indefinitely

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, forkjoinpool

I was playing around with using a custom `ExecutionContext` for my futures based code so that whenever the user decided to interrupt the program, whatever concurrent activities that are going on would be interrupted the first time they try to schedule another `Future` to be processed, and the program could exit, as opposed to having to wait for whatever long-running tasks to complete.

However, the `Executor.shutdownNow` call causes a `java.lang.InterruptedException` coming from the first `sleep(500)`, which however never reaches the `Await.result` and thus nor the `catch` or `finally` blocks; also, the program just hangs indefinitely.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool

object test extends App {
  val executor = new ForkJoinPool
  implicit val execCtx: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(executor)

  try {
    Await.result(
      for {
        _ <- future { blocking { println(1); Thread.sleep(500); println(2) } }
        _ = executor.shutdownNow
        _ <- future { blocking { println(3); Thread.sleep(500); println(4) } }
      } yield (),
      duration.Duration.Inf)
  } catch { case _: InterruptedException =>
    println("CATCH") // not reached
  } finally {
    println("FINAL") // not reached
    executor.shutdown
  }
}
```

when run (using SBT's `runMain test` if it matters), this is the output:

```
1
shutting down[error] (ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13) java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(test.scala:20)
    at test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(test.scala:20)
    at test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(test.scala:20)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.package$.blocking(package.scala:50)
    at test$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(test.scala:20)
    at test$$anonfun$1.apply(test.scala:20)
    at test$$anonfun$1.apply(test.scala:20)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: When I ran it, I got as output "1 shutting down 2 3 4 FINAL", without any exception being thrown. I then tried it again, and did get an Exception. There is a race condition here somewhere.

Comment: If you put `_ = executor.shutdownNow` between those two `_ <- future { ... }` calls, you should consistently get errors.